# integration tests against different databases

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, integration-testing

I am working on [`spwrap`](https://github.com/mhewedy/spwrap) to simplify calling to stored procedures.

Currently I wrote a couple of automated integration tests against HSQL which provides in-memeory database mode (and run on [`travis-ci`](https://travis-ci.org/mhewedy/spwrap)).

Still I need to write more integration tests against other DBMS, example MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6734410/#41482758), I can use [MariaDB4j](https://github.com/vorburger/MariaDB4j) for MySQL in-memory testing.

But what about other DBMS in particular SQL Server and Oracle?

**UPDATE**: [Is HSQLDB database compatibility sufficient?](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/guide.html#compatibility-chapt)

Comment: Please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Nitish could you please refer to which rule I am violating?

Comment: You are not asking a real question, or more specifically "But what about [other products]?" is not a good question, as you haven't defined the problem at all, just that you want to do integration tests.

Comment: I agree with you, still i need advise.

Comment: How can we give you advise if you don't ask a clear question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to run on docker/docker-compose:

> An important part of any Continuous Deployment or Continuous
>   Integration process is the automated test suite. Automated end-to-end
>   testing requires an environment in which to run tests. Compose
>   provides a convenient way to create and destroy isolated testing
>   environments for your test suite. By defining the full environment in
>   a Compose file you can create and destroy these environments in just a
>   few commands

https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/#automated-testing-environments

BTW, Travis-ci support `docker`