# How to write in test case with in-memory-database?

Tags: java, oracle, unit-testing, testng, in-memory-database

I am using Oracle as my database, Spring Boot as my framework.

I don't know how to write a test case to check database query?
I have heard that it is possible through In-Memory Database. But don't find a proper example.

Suppose in my code I have written a SQL query that `SELECT * FROM tableName` and it is returning me a ResultSet Object.

So in while writing test case how can I check that?

Every time I don't want to go into the database and fetch a query.

I know that is possible but my question is how can I replace my query's result with a dummy result which I will store in any file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Read the docs? What have you tried?

Comment: I think you can create an initial SQL script and fill in your in-memory database (like H2 for example) in @Before block of your unit test. It helps you to know current actual state of you database. You can modify this initial script with improvement of you domain model.

Comment: You can find this useful https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-hibernate

Comment: Probably Your answer [In memory DB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66259759/410439)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should initialize your Hibernate `SessionFactory` with another hibernate config, that uses H2 in-memory database, example `test-hibenate.properties`:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:h2:mem:orm
javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action=drop-and-create
```

Then in your tests you can use your DAO's just in regular way.

If you use plain JDBC, you can create connection to H2 in-memory database this way:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1", "", "");
```

And you will need H2 database dependency:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2